# Conditional classes on elements in Vue where we may have multiple options

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to add conditional classes to a div in Vue where I can have up to 3 class options based on the value of the bound data.

I think I need something like what I have below, but obviously the syntax is incorrect.
So in the example 'class-option1' is the class I'd like to apply where the bound data {{record.styleOption}} is equal to the value 'option1', and so on.

Can anyone suggest what needs changed?

```
<div :class="{
    'class-option1': {{record.styleOption}} === 'option1',
    'class-option2': {{record.styleOption}}=== 'option2',
    'class-option3': {{record.styleOption}}=== 'option3',
}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove `{{ }}` arround the bound data:

```html
<div :class="{
    'class-option1': record.styleOption === 'option1',
    'class-option2': record.styleOption === 'option2',
    'class-option3': record.styleOption === 'option3',
}">
```